# How to run a PowerShell script from Cygwin SSH session?

Tags: windows, ssh, powershell, cygwin, copssh

I have Windows Server 2003 with [CopSSH](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CopSSH) installed on it ( Cygwin + sshd ). I would like to be able to run a PowerShell script via SSH session command and then use its output. Is there such a capability? How to do it?

Comment: For those who want to know how to do it, see answer by @malloc4k

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Just invoke `powershell` with the relevant arguments and pipe it to wherever you want it? You need to make sure it's in the `PATH` of course.

Comment: Thanks. I did not think it's that simple.

Comment: It's not that simple. PowerShell uses the Console API; Cygwin (in the hands of experienced users) is not run in the console, it's run in a terminal emulator. PowerShell doesn't work in a terminal; it hangs because it's trying to use ReadConsoleInput instead of ReadFile on standard input.

Answer (score 13):

Barry Kelly is right.

You need to use my wrapper software that creates a hidden console and runs PowerShell on it.

My page is here:
http://sergeybelous.com/SHELL-TERMINAL.html#proxywinconsole.exe

Someone already found my wrapper software and created a tutorial here:
https://ssh-with-powershell.blogspot.com/2013/07/enable-ssh-with-powershell-and-remove.html

Comment: The URL needs to be updated.  Getting 404.

Comment: @HansDeragon I am about to submit an edit updating the URL (I thought it was dead, turns out it just needs an update.) But it'll still be the http version because Firefox flashes up a security warning due to the self-signed certificate on the https version. I know there's nothing to worry about, but some people clicking the link might not look too closely.

Answer (score 9):

First thing it is good to add PowerShell's executable path to user's PATH environmental variable. We do it by adding to user's .bashrc file line like:

```
export PATH=${PATH}:"/cygdrive/c/WINDOWS/system32/WindowsPowerShell/v1.0"
```

Then we can run PowerShell script just typing in our SSH session

```
powershell.exe -File "c:\u.ps1"
```

Of course now we can pipe it to use it's output.

I just wonder why I have to press "Enter" two times in my SSH session after typing the command for it to work.

Comment: To avoid having to hit return, run the command like: `echo "\n" | powershell.exe ...`

Comment: SIngle quotes are also valid - `echo '\n' | powershell.exe ...` - and if you use Git Bash instead of Cygwin, you can press ENTER once without having to pipe in an echoed newline.

Comment: I've also tried this in msys2 msys, but it failed because their `/usr/bin/cmd` clashed with `cmd.exe`. I've edited the `$PATH` to put the system32 folder at the start, and so far this seems to fix it without any side-effects.

Comment: @malloc4k Can I ask where you found out that this was possible? I can't find anything else online about invoking PowerShell from a different type of shell and using a "-File" or "/File" parameter to specify a script.

Comment: Er, never mind. I just tried `powershell -help` and got the information I needed.

Answer (score 4):

Try it with no inputformat

`powershell.exe -inputformat none -noprofile echo hello`

Can be useful for not having to deliver a file to the local machine.

Answer (score 3):

If you need to run powershell inside cygwin/babun, follow https://code.google.com/p/mintty/issues/detail?id=56#c64 . Bascilly, downloard or compile https://github.com/rprichard/winpty, copy it to your $PATH and then run

```
console.exe powershell
```

This also works with batch scripts that invoke powershell inside.

Answer (score 0):

```
Administrator@AAAAA-11111:~ $cd /cygdrive/c/WINDOWS/system32/WindowsPowerShell/v1.0
Administrator@AAAAA-11111:/cygdrive/c/WINDOWS/system32/WindowsPowerShell/v1.0 $ cmd /k powershell.exe
Windows PowerShell
Copyright (C) 2016 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

PS C:\WINDOWS\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0>
```

this works for me.